# issue with tf.data.experimental.rejection_resample?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm working on image classification(multi_labels) model, and dataset is imbalanced, I'm trying to balance the data by using the "tf.data.experimental.rejection_resample" method, but i keep getting the below error:

***"ValueError:Shape must be rank 3 but is rank 2 for '{{node Tile}} = Tile[T=DT_FLOAT, Tmultiples=DT_INT32](ExpandDims, Tile/multiples)' with input shapes: [1,9,9], [2]."***

please find the blocks of code:

1)Building function to get the label from dataset:

```
def class_func(features, label):
return label
```

2)Create the re-sampler (target dist argument is set according to the number of (labels=9):

```
resampler = tf.data.experimental.rejection_resample(
class_func, target_dist=[0.115, 0.109,0.115, 0.109,0.115, 0.109,0.115, 0.109,0.104])
```

3)Run the resampler by using .apply function (dataset has been unpatched as per the tensorflow recomendaition(see the reference [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#rejection_resampling))

```
resample_train_dataset = train_dataset.unbatch().apply(resampler).batch(10)
```

*Note: I tried to change the dims for tensor by using tf.expand_dims but it didn't work, Any idea how to resolve this issue?*

Comment: Please see how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is unclear what `train_dataset` is here.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to resampling, `rejection_resample` also transforms your dataset into a new one, where the first element is the class label used for resampling, and the second element is your original item.

So after `ds.apply(resampler)`, if you want your data back in the original format, you might do:
`ds.map(lambda extra_label, feat_and_label: feat_and_label)`